secure_file_priv still NULL after editing my.cnf macOS
I'm trying to read a csv file into my SQL database, but I'm unable to do this because of security issues with the secure_file_priv. I went through a lot of posts that have told me to edit my.cnf to allow a folder to be accessed by SQL. Currently, my my.cnf looks like this:
[mysqld]
secure_file_priv = /private/var/lib/mysql-files
pid-file = /usr/local/mysql/data/mysqld.local.pid


But, when I run
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'secure_file_priv';
I still get a value of NULL. I have also reinstalled mysql as well as restarted my database many times. While my changes in the my.cnf file are saved, there is no effect on the output.

I was also wondering if this had anything to do with no specifying a configuration file, but when I specified a path to my my.cnf file, my server would automatically stop after I started it.
EDIT: Adding content of the error log here sudo tail -f /usr/local/mysql/data/mysqld.local.err:
2024-09-21T20:38:24.709702Z 0 [System] [MY-015016] [Server] MySQL Server - end.
2024-09-21T20:38:29.338249Z 0 [System] [MY-015015] [Server] MySQL Server - start.
2024-09-21T20:38:29.487803Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld (mysqld 8.4.2) starting as process 3726
2024-09-21T20:38:29.490033Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010159] [Server] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /usr/local/mysql/data/ is case insensitive
2024-09-21T20:38:29.495667Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2024-09-21T20:38:29.575501Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2024-09-21T20:38:29.700945Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2024-09-21T20:38:29.700966Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
2024-09-21T20:38:29.712909Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.4.2'  socket: '/tmp/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
2024-09-21T20:38:29.712908Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Bind-address: '::' port: 33060, socket: /tmp/mysqlx.sock
^C
% sudo tail -f /usr/local/mysql/data/mysqld.local.err
2024-09-21T20:38:24.709702Z 0 [System] [MY-015016] [Server] MySQL Server - end.
2024-09-21T20:38:29.338249Z 0 [System] [MY-015015] [Server] MySQL Server - start.
2024-09-21T20:38:29.487803Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld (mysqld 8.4.2) starting as process 3726
2024-09-21T20:38:29.490033Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010159] [Server] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /usr/local/mysql/data/ is case insensitive
2024-09-21T20:38:29.495667Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2024-09-21T20:38:29.575501Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2024-09-21T20:38:29.700945Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2024-09-21T20:38:29.700966Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
2024-09-21T20:38:29.712909Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.4.2'  socket: '/tmp/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
2024-09-21T20:38:29.712908Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Bind-address: '::' port: 33060, socket: /tmp/mysqlx.sock

From what I can tell, I'm not seeing any errors getting logged. But, when I run the following SQL script, I get an error.
LOAD DATA INFILE '/private/var/lib/mysql-files/table.csv'
INTO TABLE Patients
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS;

ERROR:
The MySQL server is running with the --secure-file-priv option so it cannot execute this statement

Show us the content of your my.cnf and the content of the error file, to see why MySQL doesn't like it

use single quotes around the path
secure-file-priv='/private/var/lib/mysql-files'

